# Manga/graphic novel where a girl is cursed and has to enter the memories of spirits to save them

Tags: story-identification, manga, horror, supernatural, steampunk

Some 8 years ago I read some manga volumes in a very distinct style. Some words I think describe the style best is gothic and steampunk. It was in black and white but I vaguely remember the covers having brown as a main color. The story went something like this: A girl and her male friend encounter some sort of object or door that ends with the girl being cursed. In order to not die she has to go into the final memories of spirits and save them from their untimely deaths. Has strong supernatural and psychological horror elements as well as a bit of gore if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s called Bibliomania. According to the [Villains wiki](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Alice_(Bibliomania)):

> Alice, also known as the Book of Truth, is the main protagonist of the manga Bibliomania, which was loosely based on the Lewis Carroll novel Alice in Wonderland. The manga presents Alice as the 431st of 666 potential "guests" in a large serpent's "mansion", actually a book consisting of the thoughts and dreams of those it traps, creating a page designated for each, which encapsulate their deepest dreams and desires. For the majority of the manga, Alice tries to make it to the book's zeroth page, the only means of escaping, while meeting many people who were dissatisfied with their lives, along the way.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you [edit] in any details or reasons why you believe this is what the OP is looking for? Matching plot points? A synopsis perhaps? Please see [answer] for some helpful info

Comment: I added a quote but nothing I found online makes this sound like OP's story beyond superficial details (they're both horror manga with a cursed female protagonist). There's no male friend and the story was only published in 2019.

Comment: @Laurel According to [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/Bibliomania) (ObWarning) it was serialized 2016-2018, which is at least a _bit_ closer to 8 years ago.

Comment: @DavidW I think it was released on the web in 2016–2018 and got a [book](https://twitter.com/macchiro_/status/1066884979550908416) and Kindle release in 2019, all in Japanese. OP seems to be describing a manga/comic series that had several physical volumes.